# Forcing IE11 & Edge to open a site with a suspect SSL certificate

Tags: https, internet-explorer, localhost

I'm developing a site for a company from a local server. The site back-end is Hybris/Java and have no access to it.

The site is configured to serve pages as https but, as it's run on a local machine, the certificate is seen as invalid by browsers.

This is not a problem with Chrome or Firefox as you can add an exception thus 'trusting' the dodgy certificate.

However IE11 & Edge don't give the option to add the exception and simply won't display the site.

Is there a work around for this ?

[image: Screenshot from IE11]

Comment: "seen as invalid by browsers" - do you mean it's _self signed_? "and simply won't display the site" - In IE11 you should get the option to "Continue to this website (not recommended)"?

Comment: @mrWhite - Added a screenshot. I suspect that it's a proper cert but for the proper website, not our local development versions. And, as you can see, I don't get the 'continue' option.

Comment: I believe these two browsers may use Windows' own certificate store, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: The message seems to indicate weak protocol or ciphers.  Chrome just (v72) deprecated TLS 1.0, and IE is about to (I believe), but if it's fine in Chrome 72, it's probably not barking @ the protocol.  Does the cert have a Subject Alternative Names attribute with your DNS name (bbr-uk.local) in it?